# Custom Message Creation

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed the ros tutorial for creating a custom message, but I'm unsure as to where to put it. Does it go in ros_workspace/package/msg/CustomMessage.msg? Or does it go into opt/ros/electric/stacks? If so, where exactly?

I'm making a node to publish a Vehicle.msg message filled by the Joy driver. I'm using the turtle_teleop_joy tutorial as my base. I need the custom message to define the axes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28450/custom-message-creation/) by [bzt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1785/bzt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your first suggestion is correct. You put it in the `msg` directory of your message package. Make sure you then update the CMakeLists.txt to add the `rosbuild_genmsg()` option. Also, be sure to make any package using this message to depend on your message package (unless your messages are located in the same package as your node).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bzt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1785/bzt/) on 2012-02-24**:
Thanks! I thought this was the source of my error, but I see it successfully generated the msg_gen folder and files in the package folder.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-24**:
Also if other packages need to use the custom message from package A, make sure the manifest of package A exports the include cflags.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-24**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: I believe the CFLAGS export is provided automatically, now.